# Undefined reference error in Javascript for an object that is defined

Tags: javascript, singleton

I'm watching this video explaining the singleton pattern https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJ-c3BA-Ypo.
The code can be found [here](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Design-Patterns/tree/master/Singleton%20Pattern/after)

This is the code

```js
class FancyLogger {
  constructor() {
    if (FancyLogger.instance == null) {
      this.logs = []
      FancyLogger.instance = this
    }
    return FancyLogger.instance
  }

  log(message) {
    this.logs.push(message)
    console.log(`FANCY: ${message}`)
  }

  printLogCount() {
    console.log(`${this.logs.length} Logs`)
  }
}

const logger = new FancyLogger()
Object.freeze(logger)
console.log(logger)
```

I have 2 questions:

1. In the third line `FancyLogger.instance == null`, why doesn't this throw an error since `FancyLogger` was never defined?

--------I figured then out-------------
1. FancyLogger is the class name

Comment: FancyLogger *is* defined - it's the name of the class, a variable in the outer scope. *it gives me an error saying that logger is not defined* Running your snippet shows otherwise...?

Comment: `index.html` only imports `logFirstImplementation()` and `logSecondImplementation()`, so `logger` isn't visible in your console.

Comment: @Barmar, I added the following line in index.js

`import logger from './fancyLogger.js'` and it still gives me an error